# Does $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n + 4^n}{2^n + 5^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**My Attempt**

First, check the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n + 4^n}{2^n + 5^n} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n + 1} = 0.$$
So, we cannot conclude anything.
I used Comparison Test and Ratio Test.

Consider that
$$\frac{3^n + 4^n}{2^n + 5^n} < 2\frac{5^n}{2^n + 5^n}.$$
If I can proof the convergence of the series on the right-side, then it's done by comparison test.
I used ratio test, in order to proof the convergence of
$$\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} \frac{5^n}{2^n + 5^n}.$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{55^n}{2(2^n) + 5(5^n)} \frac{2^n + 5^n}{5^n} = 5 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n + 5^n}{2(2^n) + 5(5^n)} = 1.$$
I didn't find the way to proof.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advanced.

**Solution** (@abiessu & @Thomas Andrew)

Consider that
$$\frac{3^n + 4^n}{2^n + 5^n} < 2\frac{4^n}{2^n + 5^n}.$$
Proof this series converge.
$$\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{2^n + 5^n}.$$

**Proof (Ratio Test)**
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{44^n}{2(2^n) + 5(5^n)} \frac{2^n + 5^n}{4^n} = 4 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n + 5^n}{2(2^n) + 5(5^n)} = \frac{4}{5}.$$
The series converge.

Hence
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n + 4^n}{2^n + 5^n}$$
converge.

Comment: Your sum has index $i$ but there is no $i$ in the summed term. Also your sum is finite, so convergence has no meaning.

Comment: You should compare with $2\frac {4^n}{2^n+5^n}$...

Comment: Your terms are less than $\frac{4^n+4^n}{5^n}.$

Answer (score 7):

$$\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n + 1 > 1 $$
Hence

$$\frac{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n + 1} < \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n $$

And both $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$ and $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$ are general terms of a convergent geometric series.

Answer (score 7):

My preferred method would be to note that
$$
\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n+5^n}
\leq \frac{4^n+4^n}{0+5^n}
= 2 \cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n.
$$
So, the series converges by the comparison test and the geometric series criterion.

Comment: Also my preferred solution. My students know that I prefer the direct comparison test over limit comparison. I would have not done a comparison in the numerator though.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the Ratio Test. In fact,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n+5^n}}{(\frac{4}{5})^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n}\cdot\frac{5^n}{2^n+5^n}=1>0 $$
which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n+4^n}{2^n+5^n}$ converges since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{4}{5})^n$ converges.

Comment: Isn't it called the limit comparison test?